# Swift change GMSAutocompleteViewController Navbar Color

Tags: swift, colors, maps, navbar

I'm using the Google Maps Place Picker and want to change the NavBar Color.
I've tried the following the lines but both of them are working...
The Navbar stays white...
Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

```
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()

        autocompleteController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
        autocompleteController.tintColor = UIColor.blue

        autocompleteController.primaryTextHighlightColor = UIColor.jnlyDarkGrey
        autocompleteController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.black
        autocompleteController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.gray
        autocompleteController.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a little odd to me, but this works in Swift 4:

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

I'm assuming that changes it for other nav bar items in your app too, so you may have to change it back when this view controller is dismissed or another loads that needs a different style.